# NavigateUrl property of hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Please advise on how to make NavigateUrl start with the current URL, in ASP.NET.

Current URL is something like:

```
http://localhost:145/Catalog.aspx?FID=2
```

I tried "~/" but it only displays this: `http://localhost:145/`

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/") %>'
```

Is there a way to use `Request.QueryString["FID"]` here as we do in the code-behind file? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Request.RawUrl %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'<%# Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>'
```

If you want to see what else you can get from the Request.Url object:

1. Put a breakpoint inside Page_Load
2. Debug with VS
3. Type Request.Url into the Immediate window